# Consuming web service from console app

Tags: vb.net, methods, console, webservices-client

We have a web app that contains web methods. I want to invoke one of those methods from a console app. I am new at this but I wrote a console app, added a service reference and tried to code invoking it.

If my web method is called "Transmit", I expected to see Transmit in the namespace I specified but instead I see "TransmitRequest", "TranmsitRequestBody", "TransmitResponse" and "TransmitResponseBody".

What are these things?
Have I done something wrong?
How do I invoke the web method in the web app from the console app?

Thank you for all help to this newbie. I am using VB.net 2008.

Comment: You need to specify the language/platform in your tags.  I assume you're using .NET, but knowing that will definitely affect the answers you get.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I am coding in VB.net for the console app and VB asp.net for the web app.  Can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you expand the ServiceReference Folder in solutionExplorer, double click on your service and it should open the object explorer. Now you will see the class (the one without the I infront). In your code you will then instantiate a new variable with the [ServiceReferenceName].[ClassName] i.e.

```
Dim svc as new ServiceReference1.MyWebService();
svc.Transmit();
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. The problem is I am not seeing a "Transmit" method under the service name. I am seeing "Body" and some basic functions like "ToString", "GetType", etc.  Why am I not seeing the Transmit method?

Comment: That means that either the service is not configured correctly on the asmx side (methods need to be marked with [WebMethod] Attribute, or your proxy class is not being generated correctly. Select the ServiceReference in solution explorer and at the top of solution explorer click Show all files. You should have a file with the extension WSDL? look for Transmit method inside there and let me know if you can see it

Comment: The methods are marked with <WebMethod()>.  When I expand solution Explorer by Showing All Files, I do see a file with extension wsdl. However, still no Transmit method.

Comment: ok, try this, right click on serviceReference, click advanced, click add web reference and see if that works. if not then compare the exposed wsdl (by browsing to the service in browser and appending ?wsdl to the url) and see if the <wsdl:operation name="Transmit"> is in there

Comment: Ok, good. That worked. Thank you very much for helping me. I had to add a Web Reference, NOT a Service Reference. What's the difference? And where can I read up on Proxy classes, of which I know nothing?

Comment: Pleasure, please mark as answered. The difference between a web reference and service reference is that Web reference is to support legacy asp.net web service created in .Net 2.0, that's all, so a service reference is more for WCF etc. A proxy class is basically generated for you when you add the service reference by .net, you don't really have to worry about it but here are a couple of msdn links: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d2s8y7bs(v=vs.71).aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155134.aspx